# Entity Framework add local data to list from database

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I am pretty new to Entity Framework and I am using this method in order to query through my database:

```
var _context = new StudioEntities();
var results = _context.tblStudios.Select(u => new
{
    u.Standort,
    u.Name,
    u.Id
}).ToList();
```

Now my goal is to add local data as well which isn't present in the database. I tried it with this code but it didn't work:

```
results.Add(new tblStudio { Id = 0, Name = "Gesamt" });
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks

**Edit**:

My table class looks like this:

```
public partial class tblStudio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Standort { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Plz { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're performing the Add against the results object, which is just a LIst<T>, not tied to any database. Make the changes to the _context object, not the "results" object...then, call SaveChanges() to push the bits out the door to the DB.

Comment: Do you want to add new data in the database or you just want to add new data to the list retreived from the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `result` is not a `List` of `tblStudios`, it is a `List` of `Anonymous Type`. So if you want to add an item to the `result` you should do like this:

```
var results = _context.tblStudios.Select(u => new tblStudiosDTO()
{
    Standort = u.Standort,
    Name = u.Name,
    Id = u.Id
}).ToList();

results.Add(new tblStudiosDTO() { Id = "0", Name = "Gesamt" });
```

But because you cannot project onto a mapped entity then you need to create a `DTO` class like `tblStudiosDTO` with needed properties from the `tblStudios` entity.

```
public class tblStudiosDTO 
{
    public string Standort { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man but this gives me an error saying "The entity cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query". Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @Anokrize Because You cannot project onto a mapped entity. You can create a DTO class like `tblStudiosDTO` with same properties as `tblStudios`.

Comment: I included my table class in my edit. Why can I not use this class?

Comment: @Anokrize If you project onto a mapped entity, it partially loads an entity, which is not a valid state because Entity Framework won't have any clue how to handle an update of such an entity in the future!

Comment: Thank you, now it is working. You have to edit the "results.Add()"  line in your example. it is  tblStudiosDTO as well.