# LINQ - Creating a Property to Store the Result of a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have an app written in C#. In this app, I have some code that is joining some data between two data sources. That code looks like this:

```
Result result = new Result();

var items = from userOrder in UserOrders
            join product in UserProducts on userOrder.OrderId equals prodcut.OrderId
            orderby userOrder.Date, product.Name
            select new
            {
              OrderDate = userOrder.Date,
              ProductName = product.Name,
            };
result.Items = items.ToList();
```

The last line of the code creates a compile-time error that says:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: DateTime OrderDate, string ProductName>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic>'
```

As this error communicates, the `Items` property on my `Result` object is currently a `List<dynamic>`. I can change the type of this property. But, I need this property so that I can loop through the `Items` in my report. My question is, what type of property should `Items` be?

Comment: You may need to create a DTO class if this is EF. Similar:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277515/entity-framework-add-local-data-to-list-from-database

Comment: Just do `result.Items = item.Cast<dynamic>().ToList();` You many need an `AsEnumerable()` before the `Cast` if this is EF.  But you're better off creating a concrete class instead of using anonymous classes and dynamic.

Comment: Op @juharr comment is working so you should use it if you want dynamics. There is nothing to fix.

Comment: You can use a tuple instead of an anonymous class.

Answer (score 2):

You are casting this list to an anonymous object with this line:

```
select new
            {
              OrderDate = userOrder.Date,
              ProductName = product.Name,
            };
```

Try add the type of result.Items after New:

```
  select new TYPE
                {
                  OrderDate = userOrder.Date,
                  ProductName = product.Name,
                };
```

**Edit**: it looks like the type of Items may be a List of dynamic?   You should create a hard type for these. You're mixing dynamic and anonymous objects.

You could do:

```
result.Items = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)items).ToList();
```

But I usually recommend only using hard types because you gain compile type checking and don't run into errors like you are having here.

**Edit #2**: Here is an example by what i mean 'hard type'

```
 public class UserOrderProduct
            {
                public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
                public string ProductName { get; set; }
            }
```

Now the final select would be:

```
select new UserOrderProduct
           {
              OrderDate = userOrder.Date,
              ProductName = product.Name,
           };
```

And don't forget to change the type of result.Items to:

```
List<UserOrderProduct>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why it didn't work**

You are trying to assign an object to the result.Items that does not match the type defined.  result.Items is dynamic and you are assigning an anonymous type to it.

**How To Fix**

Just create a class to hold the outcome of the aggregated data.

```
public class OrderDetailsSummary
{
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

Change your Linq query to use this.

```
select new OrderDetailsSummary
{
    OrderDate = userOrder.Date,
    ProductName = product.Name,
};
```

Change the Items property on the Result class to the type OrderDetailsSummary.